# (biostrings)writeXStringSet-Error message - 'x' must be an XStringSet object

Tags: r, fasta, writetofile

I'm trying to use the Biostrings function `'writeXStringSet'`
My string is `'AAAAATTTTCCCCGGGG'`
The name of the sequence is `'NAME'`
I have tried to following script

```
writeXStringSet(seq,width=70,format="fasta"))
```

But I keep getting the following error

> 'x' must be an XStringSet object

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What the language is?

Comment: I am writing the script in r

Comment: @Pete Tagged with R to increase question visibility. Be sure to include relevant tags to increase chances of getting a response.

Comment: `seq` should be of class [`XStringSet`](http://web.mit.edu/~r/current/arch/i386_linux26/lib/R/library/Biostrings/html/XStringSet-class.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ask questions about Bioconductor packages on the Bioconductor [support site](https://support.bioconductor.org/). You have a character vector, but want a DNAStringSet (X=DNA in this case, but could also be AA if this were an amino acid sequence).

```
dna = DNAStringSet(seq)
```

Likely you intend to have names on your sequence, `c(foo="AAA", bar="ATCG")` or `names(dna) = c("foo", "bar")`, else writing in fasta format wouldn't make sense.